# Failed to load viewstate with dynamic controls

Tags: asp.net, viewstate, dynamic-controls

I have a page with two user controls (containing bootstrap modals) that are dynamically loaded. If user clicks buttonA it causes a postback and shows him `userControlA`. Similarly buttonB opens `userControlB`. Closing the usercontrols/modals is done by javascript.

The situation: The user opens `userControlA` and closes it again. He then tries to open `userControlB` which gives him "Failed to load viewstate".

My understanding of viewstate says I need to reload `userControlA` again before opening `userControlB` to avoid the exception. Is it possible to avoid the extra call to `userControlA` and open `usercontrolB` immediately? Is there a possibility to remove the viewstate information about `userControlA` when the user closes it? How can it be done?

I tried to remove `userControlA` from the html with jquery but realised that the viewstate would not be affected by this change. Have I missed some important understanding regarding viewstate?
Note that the scenario is simplified and think of the dynamic controls as heavy loaded user controls.

Comment: see if setting `EnableViewState = false;` on your user controls helps

Comment: Sure, but there are cases when I need to reload and persist the viewstate on the user control, so it is not an option.